# generating arrays both for application views and mailer the DRY way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, dry

Rails 3.2 env + ActionMailer

I need to generate variables for both a view and a notification.

So far I have the same private method in notifier.rb and application_controller.rb

How can do this DRY and the method creating the variables I need in one place only?

Comment: It depends on what given method does, you could create a helper class or use existing ActiveRecord class. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

```
module VariableGenerator

  private
  def generate_variables(data)
    @var1 = data[:var1]
    @var2 = data[:var2]
  end

  attr_reader :var1, :var2

end

class MyView
  include VariableGenerator
end

class MyNotification
  include VariableGenerator
end
```

voila!